# Выходное аудиоустройство не установлено

Tags: windows, аудио, драйвер

Acer Swift 5 sf514-53

Windows 10

Несколько раз переустанавливал Windows, не помогает. Скачивал драйвера напрямую через оф сайт, различные программы, не помогло. Параллельно с Windows стоит Ubuntu, на ней все работает.
Пробовал включить аудиоустройство через bios, там нету вкладки устройства.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]